# Jacobi sn: Does $w=\operatorname{sn}(z,m)$ send the line $\operatorname{Im}(z)=K'/2$ to the circle $\left \|w^4 \right \|=1/m?$

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

The picture below was generated in Mathematica and shows the image of a rectilinear grid in $\mathbb C$ under the elliptic mapping $\operatorname{sn}(z,m)$. The question here concerns the highlighted circle.

[image: image of a grid under Jacobi sn()]

Using the terminology of the [Wikipedia article on Jacobi elliptic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_elliptic_functions), let  $m\in (0,1],K=\operatorname{K}(m), K'=\operatorname{K}(1-m),$ and $k=\sqrt m.$

If $L$ is the line $\operatorname{Im}(z)=\tfrac 1 2K'$ and $C$ is the circle $\left \|z^4\right \|=1/m$, it looks like $C$ is the circle in the diagram, and

$$\operatorname {sn(,m)}: L \rightarrow C$$

so that for $x\in \mathbb R$

$$\left \|\operatorname{sn}^4(x+\tfrac 1 2K'i,m)\right \|=1/m.$$

Can anybody point me to a proof or exposition of the above?

Comment: With the lattice $L = 2K\Bbb{Z}+2iK' \Bbb{Z}$ and $f(x) = \sum_{l \in L} \log(1-\frac{x}{l+iK'/2})$ $+\log(1-\frac{x}{l+iK'/2+K})-\log(1-\frac{x}{l-iK'/2})-\log(1-\frac{x}{l-iK'/2+K})$ from the period and zero/pole location of $sn(x)$ then $\log sn(x+iK'/2) - f(x)$ will be analytic $L$ periodic thus constant.
As $L = \overline{L}$ then $f$ is purely imaginary for $x \in \Bbb{R}$ thus $\Re(sn(x+iK'/2))$ is constant for $x \in \Bbb{R}$

Comment: @reuns, are you saying that sn(+′/2,m) is not a circle?

Comment: I meant $\Re(\log sn(x+iK'/2))$ is constant

Comment: It also appears that the diagram is symmetric under inversion in circle $C$, so for $x,y\in \mathbb R$

$$\left \| \operatorname{sn}^2(x+(\tfrac 1 2K'-y)i,m) \operatorname{sn}^2(x+(\tfrac 1 2K'+y)i,m) \right \| =1/m$$

or slightly more compactly:

$$\left \| \operatorname{sn}(x+(\tfrac 1 2K'-y)i,m) \operatorname{sn}(x+(\tfrac 1 2K'+y)i,m) \right \| =1/k.$$

Also,

$$ \dfrac {\operatorname{sn}(x+(\tfrac 1 2K'-y)i,m)}{ \operatorname{sn}(x+(\tfrac 1 2K'+y)i,m)} \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Example 8 (pg 529) of Watson and Whittaker: A Course of Modern Analysis](https://archive.org/details/courseofmodernan00whit/page/528) states that

$$ \operatorname{sn}(u+iK'/2)=k^{-1/2}\dfrac{(1+k)\operatorname{sn}u+i\operatorname{cn}u\operatorname{dn}u}{1+k\operatorname{sn}^2u}$$

This can be derived from $$\operatorname{sn}(iK'/2)=ik^{-1/2}$$ (same book, pg 206, Example 2) and the addition formula for $\operatorname{sn}$.

Since 
$$ 
\begin{aligned} 
\operatorname{cn}(u) &= \cos(\operatorname{am}(u)) \\
\operatorname{dn}(u) &= \sqrt{1-k^2 \sin^2(\operatorname{am}(u))} \\
\operatorname{sn}(u) &= \sin(\operatorname{am}(u))
\end{aligned}
$$

we can use a change of variable $v=\operatorname{am}$ to rewrite as

$$ 
 \operatorname{sn}(u+iK'/2)=k^{-1/2}\dfrac{(1+k)\sin v+i\cos v\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 v}}{1+k\sin^2u}.
$$
Setting
$$\begin{aligned}
a &= (1+k)\sin v\\
b &= \cos v\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2 v}\\
c &= 1+k\sin^2v\\
d &= k^{-1/2}
 \end{aligned}
$$
we can further rewrite as
$$\begin{aligned} 
 \operatorname{sn}(u+iK'/2)
 &= d\left(\dfrac{a+b i}{c}\right)
 \end{aligned}
$$

For $u\in\mathbb{R}$, if we can show that $\left \|d\left(\dfrac{a+b i}{c}\right)\right\|$ is a constant for a given $k$ , then we will have shown that $\operatorname{sn}(u+iK'/2)$ is a circle.

But if $u\in\mathbb{R}$ then $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$.  So

$$
\begin{aligned}
\left \|\dfrac{a+b i}{c}\right\|^2 &= \dfrac{a^2+b^2}{c^2} \\
&= \dfrac{(1+k)^2\sin^2 v+\cos^2 v(1-k^2\sin^2 v)}{(1+k\sin^2v)^2} \\
&=\dfrac{(1+k)^2\sin^2 v+(1-\sin^2 v)(1-k^2\sin^2 v)}{(1+k\sin^2v)^2} \\
&= 1
\end{aligned}
$$

and finally
$$
\left \|\operatorname{sn}(u+iK'/2)\right\|=\left \|d\left(\dfrac{a+b i}{c}\right)\right\|=d= k^{-1/2}=m^{-1/4}\quad\blacksquare
$$